# Is there a way to select the cassandra keyspace to use in a gremlin query?

Tags: cassandra, janusgraph

Normally, the janusgraph.properties file specifies the storage backend params to which the janus instance is pointing to:

```
// For a Cassandra backend
storage.backend=cql
storage.hostname=cassandraHost
storage.cql.keyspace=myKeyspace
// ... port, password, username, and so on
```

Now, once the Janusgraph instance is created, any gremlin query requested to Janusgraph will create/read the graph info from that specified keyspace named "myKeyspace".

Since I need to use a Janusgraph instance and a Cassandra instance that already running (cannot change the keyspace), but I need the queries to return the graph contained in another keyspace called "secondKeySpace" my question is:

Is there a way to select a different Cassandra keyspace to which to point the Janusgraph gremlin queries within the gremlin query itself?

Instead of doing

````
g.V().has(label, 'service').has('serviceId','%s').out().has(label,'user')```
````

Can I do something like the next?

```
g.keySpace('secondKeySpace').V().has(label, 'service').has('serviceId','%s').out().has(label,'user')
```

Thanks in advance for any help you all, I'm new to Janusgraph and I don't know if this is even possible.

Comment: I think that you can define several graphs, like, `g1`, and `g2`, and specify different keyspaces in properties for each of them

Comment: @AlexOtt I've checked the documentation and couldn't find a reference of how to do what you are suggesting. Can you please describe your solution with a simple example?

Comment: @AlexOtt Do you mean something like this?:

Serving multiple Titan graphs over Gremlin Server (TinkerPop 3)

https://medium.com/@jbmusso/serving-multiple-titan-graphs-over-gremlin-server-tinkerpop-3-d3c971d07964

Comment: Yep, like this...